# Default Constructor of Class

Tags: scala

I have a class in Scala like this:

```
abstract class ErrorMessages(val message: String, val publicMessage: String, val objectData: Option[Object], val backtrace: Exception)
```

That I use a loot as sub classes, for example

```
case class MyError(override val message: String, override val publicMessage: String, override val objectData: Option[Object], override val backtrace: Exception) extends ErrorMessages(message, publicMessage, objectData, backtrace)
```

My quested here is can I do the last thing more easy as `case class MyError(...) extends ErrorMessages(...)` or simulary for short down the code need for create a new instance of my errpr.

Comment: Change `abstract class ErrorMessages` to `trait ErrorMessages` and then call `case class MyError(message: String,...) extends ErrorMessages`

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate all the constructor parameters into one case class, and then pass this case class on to the constructor. For example:

```
case class ErrorData(message:String, publicMessage:String, objectData:Option[Object], backtrace:Exception)

abstract class ErrorMessages(data:ErrorData)

case class MyError(data:ErrorData) extends ErrorMessages(data)
```

This probably needs some refinement. For example, you might want to make the components of `ErrorData` accessible via `ErrorMessages` as well:

```
abstract class ErrorMessages(data:ErrorData) {
  def message:String = data.message
  def publicMessage:String = data.publicMessage
  // ...
}
```

In this way, `MyError` also inherits the methods that allow direct access to `message`, `publicMessage`, `objectData`, etc. Effectively, the existence of `ErrorData` is hidden to the outside world. It's only a utility for creating instances of `ErrorMessages` subtypes. This however would also require you to reintroduce the `override` modifiers from your example.

Here is an alternative design:

Maybe you also want to skip the constructor altogether. You can do so by making the components of `ErrorMessages` abstract. Example:

```
abstract class ErrorMessages { // could also be a trait now
  def message:String
  def publicMessage:String
  def objectData:Option[Object]
  // ...
}
```

In this case, you could implement your `MyError` case class just like in your example, save for the `override` modifiers. This would circumvent the passing-up of the constructor parameters completely, and as an added bonus, leave open to the implementor how he wants to implement those abstract methods. (For example, you could have a subtype implementation whose public message is always the same as the message.)

Finally, you can be creative and combine those strategies. Maybe you do not want to integrate all of the constructor parameters into a single big case class, but just some of them that fit together thematically. When you have a lot of constructor parameters, sometimes that can be a sign that you need more integrative data types. Example:

```
case class Message(internalText:String, publicText:String)
case class ErrorOrigin(objectData:Option[Object], backtrace:Exception)

trait ErrorMessages { // you can use the constructor approach or abstract members, as shown here
  def message:Message
  def origin:ErrorOrigin

  def internalMessageText = message internalText
  def publicMessageText = message publicText
  def objectData = origin objectData
  def backtrace = origin backTrace
}

case class MyErrorMessage(message:Message, origin:ErrorOrigin) extends ErrorMessages
```

Or you can mix both ways up:

```
abstract class ErrorMessages(val origin:ErrorOrigin) {
  def message:Message

  def internalMessageText = message internalText
  // ...
}

case class MyErrorMessage(message:Message, override val origin:ErrorOrigin)
```

Not sure if this separation is good for you, or if those type and member names make sense in your case. But I hope you see the picture: There are some notable alternatives, you can play around with them and choose what fits best.

However, there is no way to leave out the passing-up of inherited constructor parameters. It would be kinda nice to have a literal `...` construct where the Scala compiler would fit in all the super type constructor parameters that have the same names as in the subtype, but such a feature doesn't exist.